# How to initialize Object of a class with primitive types

Tags: java, java-8

I have seen various threads and most of them talk about default values like primitive are initialized with **0** and Wrappers are initialized with **null**.
My question is specific and with example rather than just concept.

My class:

```
public class Subject {
    int subCode;
    int marks;
    long CGPA;

    public Subject(int subCode, int marks, long CGPA) {
        this.subCode = subCode;
        this.marks = marks;
        this.CGPA = CGPA;
    }

}
```

Now here goes my Map in Main class:

```
Map<Integer,List<Subject>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put(Integer.valueOf(1),new Subject(001,70,29l));
```

I am getting error in `29l`, i tried various forms like `Long.Valueof(29)`, but they dont work.

Can anyone tell me the concept of when there is primitive types in filed of a class then how to make instance of class using constructor.

> **Note:** I am fully aware that i should use Wrapper class here, but now i wanna try with primitive, it is just for my learning.

Thank you.

Comment: "_I am getting error in 29l_" What is the error? Also, your map says it takes a list of Subject but you only provide a single one.

Comment: you have `List<Subject>`... but adding `new Subject(001,70,29l)`...

Comment: Your Map holds a value of type List but you are trying to put a value of type Subject..

Comment: Note you should not write your first parameter as `001` unless you really want an octal number.

Comment: Primitive `29L` is the most correct since the parameter is declared a primitive `long` (not a `Long` object). Always use uppercase `L` in `29L` since lowercase letter l is so easily misread for digit 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
Map<Integer,List<Subject>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
```

You declare that the **value** of the map are: **lists**.

Then you try to add a **single** instance of the subject class!

```
    map1.put(Integer.valueOf(1),new Subject(001,70,29l));
```

Cant work!

```
    map1.put(1, Collections.singletonList(new Subject(001,70,29l)));
    map1.put(1, Arrays.asList(new Subject(001,70,29l)));
    map1.put(1, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Subject(001,70,29l))));
```

should all work. (note: I didnt run the above through a compiler, so ignore stupid typos and such. And: the first two examples will give you lines that will **not** allow you to add/remove items from those lists)

And your wording implies a misconception on your side: a List isn't a "wrapper". It is a **container**. A box in which you put things. And when you say: my map shall hold egg-boxes, then that map wants egg-boxes, and not individual eggs!